# Why not use the Result variable directly when returning object?

Tags: delphi

I've seen in a lot of examples creating a variable with the same type as the Result and assigning to it at the end of the function instead of just using the Result variable in the first place.

For instance in a code inside System.JSON

```
class function TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
  const Data: TArray<Byte>; 
  const Offset: Integer; 
  const ALength: Integer; 
  Options: TJSONParseOptions
): TJSONValue;
var
  Parent: TJSONArray;
  Answer: TJSONValue;
  Br: TJSONByteReader;
begin
  Parent := TJSONArray.Create;
  Answer := nil; { Why not just use Result directly here? }
  Br := TJSONByteReader.Create(
          Data, 
          Offset, 
          ALength, 
          TJSONParseOption.IsUTF8 in Options
  );
  try
    ConsumeWhitespaces(Br);
    if 
      (ParseValue(Br, Parent, TJSONParseOption.UseBool in Options) = ALength) 
      and
      (Parent.Count = 1)
    then
      Answer := Parent.Pop; { Why not just use Result directly here? }
    Result := Answer; 
  finally
    Parent.Free;
    Br.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Why create the variable Answer instead of just using Result?

Is this just the way the programmer decided to do it or is there a reason behind it?

Comment: Too many java programmers hired, not familiar with Object Pascal syntax?

Comment: Either approach works fine, it is just a matter of coding style. You can certainly use the `Result` directly if you want to. Either way, just be sure to call `Free` on the output object if an error occurs before the function exits, or you will have a memory leak (the above code does not have that protection - shame on Embarcadero for that!).

Comment: @RemyLebeau How could this leak? There would have to be an exception after `Answer := Parent.Pop`. It is safe to assume that there isn't. Of course, `Parent` could be leaked quote easily.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `Parent` is leaked if `TJSONByteReader.Create` raises an exception.

Comment: @Remy No. If `TJSONArray.Create` raises then `Parent` is not assigned and nothing leaks. You are of course right about `TJSONByteReader.Create` raising. My comment refers to that. However you said the output object could leak. And that's not the case here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in THIS example, the output object is not leaked, yes.  But IN GENERAL, if you create an object for output, and then an exception is raised before the function exits, make sure to destroy the output object or it will be leaked. That is what my original comment was trying to state.

Comment: @remy fine, this just wasn't a very good example to illustrate the point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this just the way the programmer decided to do it or is there a reason behind it?

There is no good reason for using an extra local variable here. Doing so just adds complexity. I would write it like this:

```
class function TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
  const Data: TArray<Byte>; 
  const Offset: Integer; 
  const ALength: Integer; 
  Options: TJSONParseOptions
): TJSONValue;
var
  Parent: TJSONArray;
  Br: TJSONByteReader;
begin
  Parent := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    Br := TJSONByteReader.Create(
      Data, 
      Offset, 
      ALength, 
      TJSONParseOption.IsUTF8 in Options
    );
    try
      ConsumeWhitespaces(Br);
      if (ParseValue(Br, Parent, TJSONParseOption.UseBool in Options) = ALength)
      and (Parent.Count = 1) then
        Result := Parent.Pop
      else
        Result := nil; 
    finally
      Br.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Parent.Free;
  end:
end;
```

This also corrects the lifetime management and a potential memory leak, as discussed in comments.